# Elementary Substructures vs. Structures

Tags: logic, definition, model-theory

Here is the definition according to Wikipedia of what an elementary substructure is:

[image]

I am just wondering about the last part, where it says it follows that $N$ is a substructure of $M$. Why? Because elementary embedding preserves the truth of all $\sigma$-formulas?

Comment: Yes, and in particular the atomic formulas...

Comment: @AlexKruckman Do you mean the atomic formulas as in function symbols and relation symbols?

Comment: No, I mean atomic formulas. An atomic formula is a formula of the form $t = t'$, where $t$ and $t'$ are terms, or $R(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, where $R$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for Wikipedia's definition to make sense, we must have $N\subseteq M$.

Now for every $n$-ary relation symbol $R$ and all elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in N$, we have $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^N$ iff $N\models R(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ iff $M\models R(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ iff $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^M$.

And for every $n$-ary function symbol $f$ and all elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in N$, we have $f^N(a_1,\dots,a_n) = b$ iff $N\models f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = b$ iff $M\models f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = b$ iff $f^M(a_1,\dots,a_n) = b$.

So $N$ is a substructure of $M$.

Note that only used that $N$ and $M$ agree on the truth of atomic formulas with parameters in $N$. In fact, the following are equivalent:

- $N$ is a substructure of $M$.
- $N$ and $M$ agree on the truth of atomic formulas with variables interpreted in $N$.
- $N$ and $M$ agree on the truth of quantifier-free formulas with variables interpreted in $N$.

Then $N$ is an *elementary* substructure of $M$ iff $N$ and $M$ agree on the truth of *all* formulas with variables interpreted in $N$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in replying to me and helping me understand this. You are truly master of logic!